# How to go to a specific pdf page in iframe with a link?

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, hyperlink, target

I want to go to a specific  pdf page in an iframe, but I don't know why it doesn't work
I want the pdf page to change inside the iframe

```
<a HREF="test.pdf#page=4&zoom=150" target="iframe_a">go to page</a>


<iframe name="iframe_a" src="test.pdf" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe id="changeiframe" height="100%" width="100%"src="https://example.com/"></iframe>

<button onclick="changepage()">go to page</button>

<script>
function changepage() {
document.getElementById("changeiframe").src = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can possibly have multiple pdf files, to act like your changing a page